# spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3, dependency-management

I just found one daunting thing. There are two versions of spring dependency coordinates.

Project has dependencies on spring mvc and spring flow. There are two parallel sets of dependencies.

Spring MVC has dependencies of the following scheme: `org.springframework:spring-asm`.

Spring Flow has dependencies of the following scheme: `org.springfrmaework:org.springframework.asm`.

Why are there two different sets of the same dependency? How can it be overcome?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you give full coordinates of these (MVC and Flow) dependencies?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov, added mvc and flow dependencies

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think they changed naming convention with Spring 3 release. I'd recommend to use (if possible) single Spring version throughout the project. If not, I'd exclude `asm` from `webflow` and keep it in `webmvc`.

Comment: Everything is documented at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#dependency-management

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically a question of the artifacts you are using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Is an artifact from the [SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/) and those artifacts are OSGi compliant. I quote:

> Welcome to the SpringSource Bundle Repository. Here you'll find
>   OSGi-ready versions of hundreds of open source enterprise libraries
>   that are commonly used when developing Spring applications.

On the other hand, you have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Is a standard artifact from [the maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.4.RELEASE).

[org.springframework.asm](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.asm&version=3.0.4.RELEASE&searchType=bundlesBySymbolicName&searchQuery=org.springframework.asm)

Is a patched version of the asm artifact for use with OSGi.

The best solution to fix this is only using the SEBR repository artifacts.

I recommend this because one time I had a problem with the jars from the maven central repo (they were corrupt) so I try to use the SEBR for any spring dependency. But I quote [from the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#dependency-management):

> If OSGi does not matter to you, either place works, though there are
>   some pros and cons between them. In general, pick one place or the
>   other for your project; do not mix them. This is particularly
>   important since EBR artifacts necessarily use a different naming
>   convention than Maven Central artifacts.

Comment: I think you should add a link to [1.3.1 Dependency Management and Naming Conventions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#dependency-management) from the documentation - all things are well explained here

Comment: @BorisTreukhov keen observation.

Comment: `webmvc` does not seem to be present in `EBR` repository, or I am missing something?

Comment: the naming convention may differ, check for packages inside webmvc on the EBR